# Two identities on set theory

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, outer-measure

I was reading extension of measure from the book 'An Introduction to Measure and Integration' by I.K.Rana. In a theorem of that book he proves how to get a complete measure space from an ordinary measure space (theorem 3.11.8, page-92). In the proof of that theorem he has used two identities of set theories. I am unfamiliar to those identities and seems very nontrivial to me. I cannot prove the the identities even after few attempts. The identities are:
$$E\cup N=(E\setminus A)\triangle (A\cap(E\cup N))$$ &
$$E\triangle  N=(E\setminus A)\cup (A\cap(E\triangle N)),$$ where $N\subset A$. Although I see from Vein diagram that the identities are correct. But I want a formal proof. Please help me out.

Comment: Just to be certain $\triangle$ is symmetric difference, right?  $$X\triangle Y = X\setminus Y \cup Y\setminus X?$$

Comment: @saulspatz yeah!

Comment: Looks like a mess, all right.  Have you tried using indicator functions?

Comment: No I don't know what indicator function is.

Comment: Too long for a comment.  I'll write an answer, but I'll leave the calculations to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see that $E\setminus A=(E\cup N)\setminus A$, so we can simplify the first equality as
$$C=(C\setminus A)\triangle (C\cap A),$$
where $C=E\cup N$. But $(C\setminus A)$ and $(C\cap A)$ are disjoint, so the symmetric difference is just a union.
Similarly, you can see that $E\setminus A= (E\triangle N)\setminus A$, and you can simplify the equality.

Note that we need $N\subseteq A$ to prove both equalities.

Answer (score 1):

You can usually do these things with indicator functions.  For $A$ a subset of the universe, define $$1_A(x)=\begin{cases}1,&x\in A\\0,&x\notin A\end{cases}$$

Then we have $$\begin{align}
1_{X\cup Y}&=1_X+1_Y-1_X\cdot1_Y\\
1_{X\cap Y}&=1_X\cdot1_Y\\
1_{X\setminus Y}&=1_X-1_X\cdot1_Y\\
1_{X\triangle Y}&=1_X+1_Y-2\cdot1_X\cdot1_Y\\
\end{align}
$$ 
Also, since we are given $N\subset A$, we know that $$
1_N\cdot1_A= 1_N$$
This gives a rather mindless way to verify set identities.

Comment: @Bungo Yes, thanks.  I'll fix it.